# Vector-Viewing Properties on Multipoint Geometric Correction in Erdas Imagine 2014?

Tags: vector, erdas-imagine, multipoint

I am following some old instructions that are not up to date with my latest version of Erdas Imagine. Where can I find the Vector viewing properties within the Multipoint Geometric Viewer?

The instructions state: "The default background color for the vector road coverage is white and the default color for
the roads is black. You can change the default road color by clicking on Vector and then
Viewing Properties."

I have attached 2 screenshots. The first one is a screenshot that came within the instructions which shows the vector option in the viewer, and the second screenshot is what I see in my version of Erdas.

[image]

[image]